# ConfigurationManager RefreshInterval vs AutomaticRefreshInterval

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configurationmanager

Can someone explain to me the difference between AutomaticRefreshInterval and RefreshInterval, i'm using ConfigurationManager in my OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider implementing IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider, by default AutomaticRefreshInterval is set to 5 days and RefreshInterval to 30 seconds, i can't find a clear explaination between those two values, the goal is to prevent resquesting metadata frequently and request them only after 1 hours for example, is the default configuration is ok or i have to change the RefreshInterval

My OpenIdConnectCachingSecuritytokenProvider class

```
 public class OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider : IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider
{
    public ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> _configManager;
    private string _issuer;
    private IEnumerable<SecurityToken> _tokens;
    private readonly string _metadataEndpoint;

    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _synclock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(string metadataEndpoint)
    {
        _metadataEndpoint = metadataEndpoint;
        _configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(metadataEndpoint);
        //_configManager.RefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
        //_configManager.AutomaticRefreshInterval
        RetrieveMetadata();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the issuer the credentials are for.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The issuer the credentials are for.
    /// </value>
    public string Issuer
    {
        get
        {
            RetrieveMetadata();
            _synclock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _issuer;
            }
            finally
            {
                _synclock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all known security tokens.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// All known security tokens.
    /// </value>
    public IEnumerable<SecurityToken> SecurityTokens
    {
        get
        {
            RetrieveMetadata();
            _synclock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _tokens;
            }
            finally
            {
                _synclock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    private void RetrieveMetadata()
    {
        _synclock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = Task.Run(_configManager.GetConfigurationAsync).Result;
            _issuer = config.Issuer;
            _tokens = config.SigningTokens;
        }
        finally
        {
            _synclock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```